# Combining these two queries into a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

These two queries work:

```
SELECT
u.id,
u.email,
COUNT(*) as Current
FROM
users u,
rounds cur
WHERE
cur.user = u.id
AND u.email = 'foo@foo.com'
GROUP BY cur.user;

SELECT
u.id,
u.email,
COUNT(*) as old
FROM
users u,
rounds__20120311_010951 old
WHERE
old.user = u.id
AND u.email = 'foo@foo.com'
GROUP BY old.user;
```

But I really want to do this:

```
SELECT
u.id,
u.email,
COUNT(old.*) as March11,
COUNT(cur.*) as Current
FROM
users u,
rounds cur,
rounds__20120311_010951 old
WHERE
old.user = u.id
AND cur.user = u.id
AND u.email = 'foo@foo.com'
GROUP BY old.user, cur.user
```

I think the syntax error is from this COUNT(**old**.*)  but I don't know for sure.

Is it possible to combine those queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY u.id, u.email`. Then, in your select, use `COUNT(old.id)` and `COUNT(cur.id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You also may use this query -

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  old.cnt as March11,
  cur.cnt as Current
FROM
  users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, COUNT(*) cnt FROM rounds GROUP BY user) cur
  ON u.id = cur.user
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, COUNT(*) cnt FROM rounds__20120311_010951 GROUP BY user) old
  ON u.id = old.user
 GROUP BY
   u.id
```

LEFT JOIN will show (all) records from `users` table and all related records from two joined tables.

Comment: Is the way I had written it an implied LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I thought you want this;-) But you can use JOIN (as you want).

Comment: Yes, thank you!  But what I was wondering is whether listing multiple tables the way I did was really a left join under the hood?

Comment: Multiple tables in FROM list and multiple condtitions in WHERE clause will show result the same as a query with INNER JOINs.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I had heard something about this but could not recall.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should looks like:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.email,
  COUNT(old.user) as March11,
  COUNT(cur.user) as Current
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN rounds cur ON cur.user=u.id
LEFT JOIN rounds__20120311_010951 old ON old.user=u.id
WHERE u.email = 'foo@foo.com'
GROUP BY u.id;
```